# Microsoft Next Android Lock Screen App

Tags: android, android-layout, lockscreen

What is the approach to creating an app like Microsoft's Next Lock Screen (Android) app?

[image: Microsoft Next Android App]

I checked out the github project below only to find out that TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG has been deprecated.

https://github.com/Joisar/LockScreenApp

I got to create a home screen that gets triggered every time the power button is pressed but the back button and home button do not disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Adenda](http://www.adendamedia.com/) SDK for that. It essentially extends the Android stack to let you build a custom lock screen with relative ease.

I'm affiliated with Adenda, btw, for full disclosure.